# How can I use emacs-lisp to prevent writing or creating a file named ":w"

Tags: file, emacs

I mistakenly created a file named ":w" because I use the evil plugin in emacs, so I want to use emacs-lisp to prevent creating or writing a file by that name. I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
    ;; prevent creating a new file named ":w", because it's always a mistake
    (defun th-guard-file-not-mistake-w ()
      (interactive)
      (if (string= buffer-file-name ":w")
          (message "You probably don't want to write a :w file")
        (message "buffer-file-name: %s" buffer-file-name)
        )
      )
    
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'th-guard-file-not-mistake-w)
    (add-hook 'write-file-hook 'th-guard-file-not-mistake-w)
```

Comment: which version of emacs are you using? try `write-file-hooks`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was based on a typo: `write-file-hook` instead of the correct name `write-file-hooks` (which is an alias for the more conventional name `write-file-functions`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `write-file-hooks`*(not hook)* works for me.

```lisp
(defun th-guard-file-not-mistake-w ()
  (interactive)
  (when (string= (buffer-name) ":w")
    (warn "You probably mistake write a :w file")
    (warn "buffer-file-name: %s" buffer-file-name)))


(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'th-guard-file-not-mistake-w)
```

I used `warn` instead of message. `buffer-file-name` matches the whole path, so you need `buffer-name` instead.

PS warning for `write-file-hooks`:
This variable is obsolete since 22.1; use `write-file-functions`
instead.